# How can I retrieve a list item's attachments, or at least the paths to the attachments from SharePoint via the Silverlight Client Object Model?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I've got a SharePoint site that I'm putting a Silverlight frontend on using the Silverlight Client Object Model. One of the lists I need to pull the data for has attachments. I need to find a way to list those attachments but I can't seem to find a way to do so.

There's an "Attachments" field on the ListItem but it's only a boolean stating whether an attachment exists or not.

I've seen plenty of examples of this using SPListItem, but how would I go about doing this using the Silverlight Client Object Model instead?

Comment: Please look in to the below blog post, [http://vangalvenkat.blogspot.com/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-getting-list-item.html](http://vangalvenkat.blogspot.com/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-getting-list-item.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have also run into this problem and with the help of answer from ScottyG30 and answer on [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/46740bf2-7030-4e87-872c-f20349cd3957/) I wrote a function for retrieving attachment from ListItem:

```
// this method needs to be executed in background thread
public String[] GetAttachments(ClientContext ctx, List list, ListItem item)
{
    // these properties can be loaded in advance, outside of this method
    ctx.Load(list, l => l.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);
    ctx.Load(ctx.Site, s=>s.Url);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    // get the item's attachments folder 
    Folder attFolder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl( list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Attachments/" + item.Id);
    FileCollection files = attFolder.Files;
    // I needed only urls, so I am loading just them
    ctx.Load(files, fs => fs.Include(f => f.ServerRelativeUrl));
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    // now you have collection of files
    return (from file in files select ctx.Site.Url + file.ServerRelativeUrl).ToArray();
}
```

While this works for me, it doesn't seem to me as best solution when you need attachments (urls) for all items in large list (every item is `executing query`).

Comment: I had problems with the return. I was able to do it just fine in a for loop though. Everything else works great.

Comment: This got me far enough to actually retrieve the files.  Next step is to download from remote server and store on local server.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClientContext spContext = ClientContext.Current;
File.OpenBinaryDirect(spContext, spContext.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/[ListName]/Attachments/[ItemID]/[File Name]", (w, f) =>
        {
            var foo = f.Stream;

        }, (q, w) => { 
            handler(this, new Exception(w.Message)); 
        });
```